# How to create a SCSM Email subscription for when the action log of a PROBLE is updated

Tags: scsm-2012

Sorry about the title, it wouldn't let me use the word PROBLEM.

In our SCSM we have used [SCSM 2012: Notify the analyst when an end-user comment is added to an incident](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/ef5a80e6-af12-4cba-9d9f-3798944035f1/scsm-2012-notify-the-analyst-when-an-enduser-comment-is-added-to-an-incident?forum=systemcenterservicemanager) to have our system automatically email the analyst when a comment is added to the incidents action log.

I would like to also be able to automatically email the assigned to user of a Problem when a comment is added to the associated problems action log is updated.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to achieve this. I hate normally pasting links without an extract, but the extract would not be sufficient to fully answer this.

Option 1: [Use Notifications](http://blogs.technet.com/b/servicemanager/archive/2013/05/13/how-to-configure-notifications-for-assignment-re-assignment-as-well-as-action-log-and-user-comment-updates-for-incidents-and-service-requests-in-scsm.aspx)

> 1. Notify the Analyst when a user adds comments from the portal for an Incident or Service Request.
> 2. Notify the End User when the Analyst updates the action log from the console for an Incident or Service Request.
>
> If you are using the Exchange connector to process emails to create
>   and update emails:
>
> 3. Notify the Analyst when an end user replies to email notifications with comments (or provides new information) for an incident or Service
>      Request.
> 4. Notify an End User when analysts reply to emails requesting more information (reply to assigned to user notification or analyst
>      notification which will be logged as Analyst comments on the Incident
>      or Service Request)
> 5. We will modify assignment/re-assignment management pack to notify for assignment or re-assignment of a Service Request.

Option 2: [Use third party tool](http://cireson.com/apps/action-log-notify/)

Option 1 in my own opinion is a better option.